# VBA IF statement works when condition is met but get mismatch error when condition not met.

Tags: vba, if-statement

VBA beginner here... This is probably a simple solution I am overlooking but I could not find other questions that fixed my issue. 
I am using the below code to delete the first row if cell B1 is not #N/A...otherwise do nothing.

```
If [B1].Value <> "#N/A" Then
[B1].EntireRow.Delete
End If
```

If the condition is met, the first row is deleted and the code works perfectly. However, if the condition is not met I get a mismatch error (instead of just moving on to the next line). Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Error `#N/A` is not a string, so the `.Value` does not actually equal the text `#N/A`; it's an `Error` value (`Error` being a data type), and an `Error` can't be coerced to/from a `String`.

You test for the error with:

```
If not IsError(ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value) Then
```

Or test the `.Text`

```
If ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Text <> "#N/A" Then
```